# $L^1_{\text{loc}}$, Frechet Space and norm-distance

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I was talking with a professor of mine, last week, and he started talking about the fact that "the space $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ is a Frechet Space, and hence you cannot put a norm into it. At most you can put a distance."

Can someone please clarify this passage to me a bit? Maybe with some example?
Or please give me some good reference where to read about those questions too.

Comment: A funny typo in your title: $L^1_{lol}$... :) ("laugh out loud?") :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Hahaha the Space of Fun! Going to correct (I would not but I have to)

Comment: He means it's a metric space but not a normed space.  You could consider reading  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_topological_vector_space#Normability and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Norms_and_normability and the references mentioned.

Comment: You can certainly put a norm on this space. But there is no norm that induces the usual topology.

Comment: @PhoemueX care to elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filling out peoples' apt comments:

Yes, $L^1_{\mathrm loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a Frechet space, with the countable collection of seminorms $\int_{|x|\le B}|f(x)|$. Really, the most important point (which requires a little proof) is that it is *complete*. The standard trick of rewriting a countable collection of seminorms into a single metric (not norm, in general!) is not so useful *except* to demonstrate that the space is metrizable (with, perhaps, no *canonical* metric): $$
d(f,g)=\sum_{\ell\ge 1} 2^{-n} {\int_{|x|\le \ell} |f(x)-g(x)|
\over 1+\int_{|x|\le \ell}|f(x)-g(x)|}
$$

The assertion that it's not *normable* really is that it has no norm *in_which_it_is_complete*. (Equivalently, there's no norm that induces the Frechet metric, which is complete.)

It takes a little work, but is standard, to show that a topological vector space (with a given topology) is *not* normable (meaning giving the same topology). This issue is discussed in most not-completely-introductory functional analysis books, expressing the necessity of introducing "fancier" structures than just Hilbert and Banach spaces.

(And to topologize the space of test functions to make them "complete", requires yet more effort, ... and then there are *dual* spaces...)

Comment: The seminorms should be $\int_{|x|\leq B} |f(x)|\, dx$.

Comment: @Michh, ooops, of course, thanks! :)

Comment: What is the norm(s) that can be put on the space (even though the result is not a Banach space)?

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! Is there any rather good book (or books) or some good notes where to learn about all this in a clear way?

Comment: @paulgarrett Just wanted to say that I am literally digging into your website and I am finding so many treasures.

Comment: @Hans-André-Marie-Stamm, I'm glad my notes are helpful! :)

Comment: @g.s, in fact, I do not know of any more-or-less-natural norm on $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$...

Answer (score 3):

As Paul Garrett rightly says, a metric on $L^1_{loc}$ is not very useful to understand its *locally convex structure*. The seminorms $\|f\|_n=\int\limits_{\{\|x\|\le n\}} |f(x)|dx$ are much more appropriate: A sequence or net $(f_\alpha)$ converges in $L^1_{loc}$ to $f$ if and only if $\|f_\alpha-f\|_n\to 0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Assuming that there is a single norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X=L^1_{loc}$ having the same convergent sequences would imply (just by abstract continuity arguments for vector spaces with seminorms) that $\|\cdot\|\le c \|\cdot\|_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and $c>0$ and that $\|\cdot\|_m \le c_m\|\cdot\|$ with constants $c_m$. This yields $\|\cdot\|_{n+1}\le \tilde c\|\cdot\|_n$ which is clearly wrong in the particular case by considering functions with support in $(n,n+1]$.